# Error creating bean with name - Grails 2.3.8

Tags: java, grails, searchable

Grails 2.3.8 error searchable plugin 6.9 - Error creating bean with name `grails.plugin.searchable.SearchableController`

> Error 2016-07-26 09:53:18,826 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'grails.plugin.searchable.SearchableController': Initialization of
>   bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'searchableService': Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on
>   object creation; nested exception is
>   org.compass.core.mapping.MappingException: No converter defined for
>   type [org.bson.types.ObjectId]

The error occurs at runtime and I can't fixed it

Comment: Are you using ObjectId somewhere in your domains as a field?

Comment: Yes I am using it in some of my domain, any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have a searchable property of type `org.bson.types.ObjectId`. This is not a type that the searchable plugin natively knows how to index, so you have to define a converter for it.

Comment: I solved the problem by anotating the ObjectId like this:  @ObjectId id
    private String id